# return a value in an event handler function

Tags: javascript

I'm absolutely out of idea now and i would like anyone with better idea to help give a concise solution to this. here is my code:

Ok what I'm trying to write here is a program that listen to the `load` event for fetching data from an api and save it in cache, then clear the cache when the user try to exit the browser. using the `opt` parameter to set when to load and unload the cache outside the method.

```
class myc {
  // ... 
  async get(url, opt = {}) {
    let js, er, data;
    if (opt.load === true) {
      window.addEventListener('load', getData);
    }
    if (opt.unload === true) {
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', removeData);
    }
    async function getData() {
      try {
        let r = await fetch(url) 
        if (!r.ok) {
          throw new Error(r.statusText)
        } else {
          js = await r.json();
        }
      } catch(e) {
        er = e.message;
      }
      if (js) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, js);
        data = localStorage.getItem(key);
      }
      // Main problem here (*)
      return {
        data : data ? data : null,
        error: er
      };
    }
    function removeData(){
      localSorage.clear();
    }
    let res = await getData();
    window.removeEventListener('load', getData);
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload, removeData);
    return res;
  }
}
```

The line with (*) is the main problem here. So how do i return the required value from that function to then be used in another instance

Comment: It does not make any sense to return a value from an event handler, other than returning `false` to signal to the browser that the event processing loop should end. Any other value will be ignored.

Comment: Can you also describe what exactly you're trying to do, instead of just pasting the code? Thanks!

Comment: I edited my question for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: you don't.

Even if you returned a value from an event handler, it would have nowhere to go because you don't have access to the thing that actually called the event handler to be able to grab that return value.

Instead, you simply set the value somewhere in the scope you can grab it later.

Since you are in a class, you could simply set it to `this.myValue` and then grab it with the same.

The only gotcha with that is you have to make sure your event handler is bound to the proper scope.

You can do that one of two ways. On this line:

```
window.addEventListener('load', getData);
```

you can bind `getData` so it looks like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', getData.bind(this));
```

That way the `this` inside of `getData` will refer to your class.

Alternatively, you could switch this line:

```
async function getData() {
```

to an arrow function syntax:

```
const getData = async () => {
```

which will automatically bind to the current context.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought of the same solution but i wasn't confident enough to implement that

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a global variable that you update in the event handler.

Using a call back function (or simply calling another function with the "return" variable value as parameter) to do some more processing is another way of achieving what you probably want.

Example:

```
async function getData(){
    //event handler doing it's task
    //create { data : data ? data : null, error: er } as global var
    var returnData = { data : data ? data : null, error: er };
    //or
    functionToDoMoreProcessing({ data : data ? data : null, error: er });
}
```